# Is there a good way to call methods in a c++ library from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, dll, .lib

I have an .exe built from an HTML5/JavaScript project using Adobe Air, and a .lib file created from a c++ project. Is there a good way to call the methods in the .lib file from JavaScript?

Comment: Good luck with that. Let us know when you've finished your research.

Comment: I researched this for about a week. The closest I got was with [QT](http://qt-project.org/). The project runs in the IDE,  but I couldn't get it to build correctly. I also looked into converting c++ to javascript with [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), but I don't think that's a very good solution. In the end, I think I'm going to be using ASP.Net for my project instead.

Comment: I'm just wanting to know if there's a good way to call c++ functions from JavaScript? I appreciate any insight.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to use Emscripten to compile the code to JS.

Comment: You should give more details on what you're trying to achieve specifically. It might be of some help: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix this is a good find, although my project parameters have been changed so I no longer need this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz when I tried this, I was getting compilation errors with even a simple c++ function.